# Sending a javascript String to PHPmailer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, phpmailer

I need to send a javascript String to a php file when it's called. I am aware of the server-side/client-side relation, but I'm guessing this case is a bit different.
The purpose of this website would be for an user to insert values on INPUT tags (many of them) and have them sent via email through PHPmailer. The problem is, I don't want any blank inputs to be sent AND I want a "label" to appear before the values in the email. The best workaround I thought of was to insert everything I want into a JS String and have it picked up by the phpmailer when the user submits the form.

Sorry for the long story, but if you think there's a better solution than mine, please speak up.

Anyway, here's the piece of code that is being a problem.

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="mailer.php">
```

I've looked around and it seems that I could send this variable through a function similar to this (which I tested and works fine):

```
var str = "This is a String variable";
function redirect(){
    window.location.href = "mailer.php?values=" + str;
}
```

If I wanted to get that variable sent by the form's ACTION atribute (If I wanted to get some variables with $_POST I'd need the submit button, right?), how would I do it?

Just to help you visualize it, here's more or less what I want:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="mailer.php$values"+str>
```

Thanks in advance for all the answers and suggestions.

@edit: I just realized what I'm basicaly asking is: How to have a SUBMIT button's ACTION changed before it accesses the php page?

I can only finish editing this String right before it's sent. Or I could re-write it every time an input loses focus but I don't think that re-writing this String, which involves an Array of 100+objects, every time something changes would be the best option.

Comment: Why not use a hidden field?  Update the value of the hidden field prior to post, and retrieve in PHP after post.

Comment: Why not send the values through to an intermediate processing / confirmation page, which then sends the processed / confirmed values on to `mailer.php` ?

Comment: @devlincarnate Thanks! That's exactly what I used with help from you and Dminones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments the best way of doing this is to place hidden files in the form via javascript.

```
var input = document.createElement("input");

input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input.setAttribute("name", "name_you_want");   
input.setAttribute("value", "value_you_want");

//append to form element that you want .
document.getElementById("contactform").appendChild(input);
```

Add the contactFormId

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" id="contactForm" action="mailer.php">
```

Note that doing this will get the values via $POST var instead GET wich makes more sense since you are sending via post your form.

Comment: Thanks! This worked just fine. I called an onclick function from Submit that  filled a hidden type input. It is also nice that I can still get any other input from the form straight from php, which I couldn't do by simply calling a function before.